# How to remove all duplicates in a 3D Array in Phyton?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, duplicates

So i have an array like this one:

```
[[['A'], ['C']], [['B', 'E'], ['G']], [['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F']], [['C', 'D'], ['F', 'E']], [['D', 'C'], ['E', 'F']], [['D', 'C'], ['F', 'E']], [['E', 'B'], ['G']], [['F'], ['H']]]
```

Now i want to remove all the duplicates in the array while different sequences dont matter so CD is the same as DC so the result should look like this:

```
[[['A'], ['C']], [['B', 'E'], ['G']], [['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F']],[['F'], ['H']]]
```

How should i do this i thought about three for loops, but is there a simple way to do this? can someone help?

Comment: Could sequences contain repeats? For instance, could we have ['A','B','A'] instead of ['A']?

Comment: No sequences do not contain repeats. In my case for the problem i am trying to solve it is impossible for them to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this:

```
arr = [[['A'], ['C']], [['B', 'E'], ['G']], [['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F']], [['C', 'D'], ['F', 'E']], [['D', 'C'], ['E', 'F']], [['D', 'C'], ['F', 'E']], [['E', 'B'], ['G']], [['F'], ['H']]]

seen = set()
for a1 in arr:
    for i in range(len(a1))[::-1]:
        a2 = tuple(sorted(a1[i]))
        if a2 in seen:
            a1.pop(i)
        else:
            seen.add(a2)
arr = [*filter(lambda x:x,arr)]
print(arr)
```

Result:

```
[[['A'], ['C']], [['B', 'E'], ['G']], [['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F']], [['F'], ['H']]]
```

Comment: Since your innermost arrays don't contain repeats, you could replace `a2 = tuple(sorted(a1[i]))` with `a2 = frozenset(a1[i])`. I'm not sure if that changes much, though